# Possibilities for the intersection of sub-line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume $X$ is a smooth projective variety, say over $\mathbb{C}$, and $E$ is a coherent torsion free sheaf of rank 2 on $X$.

If $L_1\hookrightarrow E$ and $L_2\hookrightarrow E$ are sub-line bundles such that $E/L_1$ and $E/L_2$ are torsion free, what are the possibilities for $L_1\cap L_2 \hookrightarrow E$?

Since $E$ is torsion free, the intersection can't be torsion. My hope was that either $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect trivially in $E$ or that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are actually the same sub-line bundle if they intersect non-trivially.

I am hoping that these are the only possibilities so that in case that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are known to be different sub-line bundles, then $L_1\cap L_2=0$ and $L_1\oplus L_2\hookrightarrow E$.

Are these the only possibilities? How could one prove such a fact? I think maybe something along the lines: the locus where $L_1$ and $L_2$ agree in $E$ is closed. But I haven't been able to make that work.

Or what else is possible? Are there any conditions that assure that these are the only possibilities, e.g. take $E$ even locally free?

Comment: Typically subbundles are defined for vector bundles, not torsion free sheaves. So, do you mean $E/L_1$ is torsion free when you write $L_1$ is a subbundle?

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, we may assume $E/L_1$ is torsion free. I have given a torsion free sheaf of rank two and trying to see if it is slope stable, that's why I am trying to understand sub-line bundles.

Comment: I will give you a hint. Consider the composite $L_2\to E/L_1$ and show that it is injective or zero.

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you! So either it is zero in which case I get $L_2 \hookrightarrow L_1$ or it is non zero, then it is injective as a morphism between rank one torsion free sheaves. But its kernel is $L_1\cap L_2$. By symmetry we also get $L_2 \hookrightarrow L_1$, and hence if $L_1\cap L_2 \neq 0$ then $L_1 \cong L_2$.